# Hide some part of text in the Richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: winforms, richtextbox, selection

I want to hide some part of text in the richtextbox in vb.net. 
i.e.

```
Richtextbox1.text ="Test1 test2 test3"
```

Now i want to hide "test2" from richtextbox text and it should display only "Test1 test3" text on the richtextbox control.

So anyone help me and tell me how to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it a static value that you can call Replace() against to simply remove it from the string?  If not, please give more details about the value and how you intend to find it in your actual problem.

Comment: yes it is static value and it is knows for us to replace that value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RichTextBox control does support the Visible rtf codes, so this would work:

```
string hideText = "test2 ";
if (richTextBox1.Find(hideText) > -1) {
  richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\v " + hideText + @"\v0}";    
  MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Text);
}
```

Note that the message displayed will still show "test2".

Per your comment, here is a method to hide all instances of a word by iterating backwards:

```
string hideText = "[test2]";
int index = richTextBox1.TextLength;
while (index > -1) {
  index = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(hideText, index);
  if (index > -1) {
    richTextBox1.Select(index, hideText.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\v " + hideText + @"\v0}";
  }
}
```

Comment: that works fine. but if the value of rtf is like                  richTextBox1.text = "[test2] [test1] [test2]".                       now i want to hide [test2] then how it possible.

Answer (score 0):

"yes it is static value"

This seems a trivial answer...

```
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("test2", "")
```

*Assuming the static value isn't part of another string.